# How to get entity validation errors in Entity Framework Core 3.1.31

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate an older EF6 project to a NetStandard 2.0 EF Core 3.1.31 project.  One of the final issues I'm running into is catching and reporting entity validation errors.  This is what we had previously.

```cs
catch (DbEntityValidationException dbexc)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var eve in dbexc.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"Entity of type {eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name} in state {eve.Entry.State} has the following validation errors:<br />");
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($" - Property: {ve.PropertyName}, Error: {ve.ErrorMessage}<br />");
        }
    }
    retval.ErrorMessages.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```

I can't find clear direction on how to do something similiar in EF Core.